# Calculation of center point for the localization of robot in 3D data

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, robotics, point-clouds

I am trying to find a reliable method to calculate the corner points of a container. From these corner point’s idea is to calculate the center point of the container for the localization of robot, it means that the calculated center point will be the destination of robot in order to pick the container. For this I am looking for any suggestions to calculate the corner points or may be if any possibility to calculate the center point directly.  Up to this point PCL library C/C++ is used for the processing of the 3D data. 
The image below is the screenshot of the container.
thanks in advance.

[afterApplyingPassthrough](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=11444239609089023428)

Comment: you are trying to find the center of that rectangle?

Comment: actually I didnt think about finding the center of rectangle could also somhow resolve the problem. That means if my approch is to find the corners and to calculate the center which offcourse have few steps. As you mentioned finding the center could be a better solution. Finding the center and adding the offset.  you suggest any possibilites to calculate it directly in PCL ?

Comment: Do you have any depth data there?  I dont see any of the interior surfaces of that container...  (i understand that it is 3d data, but can your sensor only resolve the front surface of the cart?)

Comment: If you see the second image( just uploaded) with better visibility of the container backward.I guess here its oriented in a way where the front is aligned with backward parts data.

Comment: Any chance you could post a irl picture of the object you are looking at?

Comment: Sure!  irl picture ?

Comment: like a phone pic or something.  It is just hard to get a feel for 3d data with a 2d snapshot of a pointcloud, so to help, a normal camera picture or somehow posting the point cloud file (.pcd) would help.

Comment: Are these newly uploaded pictures give some idea for 3d apparence. I can upload the (.pcd) as well.

Comment: lmao, i meant of the actual object like jpg from your phone of the object, haha not of your screen showing the point cloud.  Yes, the pcd would work, then i can just load it into my system and see it.

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood. sorry for that :) Here is the pcd file. and above is the picture with actual object.                               http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=55077453674107310625

Comment: Sorry, I never saw you posted this picture.  That is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the wheels maintain the cart a known offset from the floor and you can identify the floor.  Filter out all points which are too close to the floor (this will remove wheels and everything but cart which will help limit data and simplify later steps.

If you isolate the cart, you could apply a simple average point (centroid), alternately, if that is not precise, you could try finding the [bounding box](http://www.pcl-users.org/Finding-oriented-bounding-box-of-a-cloud-td4024616.html) of the isolated cart (min max in primary directions) and then take the centroid of that bounding box (this should be more accurate, but will still need a slight vertical offset due to the top handles).

If you can not isolate the cart or the other methods are not working well, you could try using [PCL sample consensus](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__sample__consensus.html) specifically SACMODEL_LINE.  This will be an involved strategy, but will give very solid results, basically run through and find each line and subtract its members from the cloud so as to find the next best line.  After you have your 4 primary cart lines, use their parameters to find your centroid.  *this would also be robust against random items being in or on the cart as well as carts of various sizes (assuming they always had linear perpendicular walls)

Comment: Great suggestions.thanks.  
 What you say regarding (1)identifiying the floor and (2)filtering out the points which are too close to the floor in order to remove wheels and to keep only the cart so afterwards I could use the (3) bounding box. ?

Comment: Those are pretty clear explanations... as far as how to actually implement it, there is far too much to explain.  It is super well documented with tutorials and web documentation of classes thought.  Here is a good place to start: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/  I suggest trying the tutorials as they are at first and then modifying them to fit your needs.

Comment: actually I've been looking into PCL tutorials and used RANSAC for plane fitting etc. Could you mention any particular example in which detection and removal of plane is possible, somehow it would be easier to filterout the wheel after, and finding a rectangular prism bounding box on the cart object ?

Comment: http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php

Comment: I tried it with different distance thresholds. The front surface of the container is fitted as the plane instead of the floor points any suggestions please.  *.pcd file is in the new link below.                                                                                                                pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> seg;
seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
seg.setDistanceThreshold (20.02);
seg.setInputCloud (cloud);
seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);

Comment: Yes and the detected plane is always the front surface of the container as it is only plane with high number of points . As my main goal is to get the centerpoint/centroid of the 3D object/container, if you look at the recently posted *.pcd file(afterApplyingPassthrough) where I used only passthroughfilter to discard the floor points and wheels assuming that the offset from floor is always known.

Comment: After applying passthrough as shown in *.pcd above. I tried to compute the centroid of the remaining object(without floor points and wheels)    1) pcl::compute3DCentroid(*cloudExtracted, centroid)                          2) as you mentioned other idea is to find the boundingbox for the remaining object. what you say which one fits better in this case.

Comment: I think compute centroid is going to give you the more robust point.  You may need to set a static offset for that point though (because of those little flaps on the top which will pull it up a little bit).

Answer (score 2):

I did the following things:

- I binarized the image (black pixels = 0, green pixels = 1),
- inverted the image (black pixels = 1, green pixels = 0),
- eroded the image with 3x3 kernel N-times and dilated it with same kernel M-times.

Left: N=2, M=1;Right: N=6, M=6

[image] [image]

After that:

- I computed contours of all non-zero areas and
- removed the contour that surrounded entire image.

This are the contours that remained:

[image] [image]

I do not know how "typical" input image looks like in your case. Since I only have access to one sample image, I would rather not speculate about "general solution" that will be suitable for you. But to solve this particular case, you could analyze every contour in the following way:

- compute rotatated rectangle that fits best around your contour (you need something similar to [minAreaRect from OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9))
- compute areas of rectangle and contour interior
- if the difference between contour area and the area of the rotated bounding rectangle is small, the contour has approximately rectangular shape
- find the contour that is both rectangular and satisfies some other condition (for example: typical area of the container). Assume that this belongs to container and compute its center.

I am not claiming that this is a solution that will work well in real world scenarios. It is also not fast. You should view it as a "sketch" that shows how to extract some useful information.

Comment: The picture I posted above is the screenshot of the pointcloud data. It means literally that the processing shouldnt be on this image but the depth data. but thankyou it seems good in case if its a 2D image. isnt it ?